# Calculate area of cross section for varying height

Tags: r, area, integral

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the area of a river cross section.

For the cross section I have the depth at every 25 cm over the 5 m wide river.

```
x_profile <- seq(0, 500, 25)
y_profile = c(50, 73, 64, 59, 60, 64, 82, 78, 79, 76, 72, 68, 63, 65, 62, 61, 56, 50, 44, 39, 25)
```

If anyone have some suggestions of how this could be done in r it's highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like an integration problem to me. I would approach it by using linear interpolation and applying the quadrature formula (the most obvious choice being [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)). The formula essentially simplifies down to a sum over `i` of `step * depth_i`, where `step = 0.5m`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `sf` package to create a polygon showing the cross-section and then calculate the area. Notice that to create a polygon, it is necessary to provide three more points as `c(0, 0)`, `c(500, 0)`, and `c(0, 0)` when creating the matrix `m`.

```
x_profile <- seq(0, 500, 25)
y_profile <- c(50, 73, 64, 59, 60, 64, 82, 78, 79, 76, 72, 
               68, 63, 65, 62, 61, 56, 50, 44, 39, 25)

library(sf)

# Create matrix with coordinates
m <- matrix(c(0, x_profile, 500, 0, 0, -y_profile, 0, 0),
            byrow = FALSE, ncol = 2)

# Create a polygon
poly <- st_polygon(list(m))

# View the polygon
plot(poly)
```

[image]

```
# Calcualte the area
st_area(poly)
31312.5
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! That looks great! Any ideas about how I could calculate the area as a function of the water level, as the water starts filling up the cross section, starting at the deepst point?

Comment: @Nicolle I don't know yet. One idea is to use a line showing the depth to split the polygon and calculate the area.

Comment: @Nicolle By the way, it is not a good idea to change your question after someone has provided an answer to the original question. I may update my answer if I have time, but I cannot guarantee that.

Comment: I am very sorry, I understand that. It was never my intention to change the question, I just tried to make it more clear. But I totally get your point.

Comment: I accepeted your answer and posed a new question regarding the calculation of the water filled part (If once you have time, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650208/calcualte-area-of-cross-section-as-function-of-height) ) Thank's for your answer!

Comment: @Nicolle Thanks for accepting my answer. And I think it is a good idea to post a new question. I will look into the new question and do some research tonight.